# How can I figure out which process caused a reboot?

Tags: macos, logs

My 2020 MacBook Air has been restarting itself every few days. I suspect an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app is going rogue and overheating my CPU. For example I use Evernote, and I often catch the renderer process chewing up my CPU. Spotify does the same at times.

I followed [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340363/20665) on how to use `logs show` to look for the culprit after a forced restart but it doesn't give any results for me on Ventura 13.4.1. Can anyone help me figure out why my computer is restarting, and in the case of an overheat, what process caused it?

Comment: I don't think a process 'going rogue' should be able to cause a reboot. Is the Mac actually just suddenly, unexpectedly restarting, with no warning, no kernel panic, no dialogs?

Comment: Correct @benwiggy , it's restarting without warning. I think it's overheating from a process that's doing things it's not supposed to (maybe some code gets triggered sporadically that results in an infinite loop — I'm not sure) . The machine is very hot to the touch when this happens; not normal in my experience with M1 machines.

Comment: You'll have to use trial and error to work out which app is causing the problem. Even so, there should be all kinds of protections before the Mac will power off because of heat.